# Marking records that don't match between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have a benchmark dataframe:

```
my_id    parent_id    attribute_1    attribute_2     attribute_3       attribute_4
  ABC          DEF             A-          378.8          Accept             False
  ABS          DES             A-          388.8          Accept             False
  ABB          DEG             A           908.8          Decline             True
  ABB          DEG             B-          378.8          Accept             False
  APP          DRE             C-          370.8          Accept              True
```

And a dataframe:

```
my_id    parent_id    Attribute_1     attribute2           attr_3        attribute_5
  ABC          DEF             A-          478.8          Decline              StRing
  ABS          DES             A-          388.8          Accept               String
  ABB          DEG             A           908.8          Accept               StrIng
  ABB          DEG             C-          378.8          Accept               String
  APP          DRE             C-          370.8          Accept               STring
```

As you can see, some mistakes appear every now and then in attribute_1, attribute_2 or   attribute_3 (the columns are named differently but they are supposed to contain the same thing).

How do I mark the faulty records when I check if, for each row, these three attributes are exactly the same as in the benchmark? I expect an output similar to this:

```
faulty_rows = 

    my_id    parent_id    Attribute_1     attribute2           attr_3       faulty_attr 
      ABC          DEF             A-          478.8          Decline       [attribute2, attr_3]                  
      ABB          DEG             A           908.8          Accept        [attr_3]      
      ABB          DEG             C-          378.8          Accept        [Attribute_1]
```

What I did was to rename the columns and always join column by column, separately, it gives me an idea about what is wrong, but I want to check the entire row at the same time and also mark where the mistake is. Is that possible? A PySpark or Pandas solution is goo either way, I am interested in the logic.

Comment: The orderr of the rows of both dataframes are consistent?

Comment: @PaulS Most likely not.

Answer (score 1):

Its mouthful in pyspark. See code and logic below

```
df1 =df1.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('my_id','parent_id')))#Create index. This can be avaoide if you have a nuique key
df =(df.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('my_id','parent_id')))#Create index. This can be avaoide if you have a nuique key
#Rename columns to make them similar with df1
     .withColumnRenamed('attribute_1','Attribute_1').withColumnRenamed('attribute_2','attribute2')
.withColumnRenamed('attribute_3','attr_3').withColumnRenamed('attribute_3','attr_3'))


s =(df1.drop('attribute_5').unionByName(df.drop('attribute_4')).orderBy('my_id','parent_id','index')#Union the two dfs and sort bt index
    .withColumn('change',array('attribute_1','attribute2', 'attr_3'))#Create an array of columns being invetsigated for change
    .withColumn('cols',split(lit('attribute_1,attribute2, attr_3'),'\,'))#Introduce list of column names being invetsigated
    .withColumn('change1',last('change').over(Window.partitionBy('index').orderBy('my_id','parent_id')))#For every index,put changes side by side
    .where(col('change')!=col('change1'))#Filter where changes are not the same
    .withColumn('change2', expr("transform(change,(c,i)->change[i]!=change1[i])"))#create boolean of chnages
    .withColumn('faulty_attr',expr('filter(cols,(x,j)->(change2[j]))'))#Leverage arrray functions to filter columns that didnt change as expected
    .drop('index','change','cols','change1' ,'change2')#drop unwated columns
   )
s.show(truncate=False)


+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|my_id|parent_id|Attribute_1|attribute2|attr_3 |faulty_attr          |
+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
|ABB  |DEG      |A          |908.8     |Accept |[ attr_3]            |
|ABB  |DEG      |C-         |378.8     |Accept |[attribute_1]        |
|ABC  |DEF      |A-         |478.8     |Decline|[attribute2,  attr_3]|
+-----+---------+-----------+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this for multiple attributes that I had to compare, and it throws an error after "split": _() takes 1 positional argument but 10 were given. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Are you able to send me just the string that you are trying to split? I will identify what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` refers to your first dict, and `B` to your second one:

**Option 1:** Using Dataframe comparison

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(B)

diffs = df1.where(df1.values==df2.values).isnull()
df1['faulty_attr'] = diffs.dot(diffs.columns)

###resulting output:
###  my_id parent_id attribute_1  attribute_2 attribute_3  attribute_4             faulty_attr
###0   ABC       DEF          A-        378.8      Accept        False  attribute_2attribute_3
###1   ABS       DES          A-        388.8      Accept        False
###2   ABB       DEG           A        908.8     Decline         True             attribute_3
###3   ABB       DEG          B-        378.8      Accept        False             attribute_1
###4   APP       DRE          C-        370.8      Accept         True
```

**Option 2:** Using `DeepDiff`

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

print(DeepDiff(A, B, ignore_order=False).pretty())

###resulting output:
###Value of root['attribute_1'][3] changed from "B-" to "C-".
###Value of root['attribute_2'][0] changed from 378.8 to 478.8.
###Value of root['attribute_3'][0] changed from "Accept" to "Decline".
###Value of root['attribute_3'][2] changed from "Decline" to "Accept"
```

**Option 3:** Using a `DataFrame` merge

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(A)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(B)

comparison_df = df1.merge(df2, indicator=True, how='outer')
print(comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == 'right_only'])

###resulting output:
###  my_id parent_id attribute_1  attribute_2 attribute_3  attribute_4      _merge
###5   ABC       DEF          A-        478.8     Decline        False  right_only
###6   ABB       DEG           A        908.8      Accept         True  right_only
###7   ABB       DEG          C-        378.8      Accept        False  right_only
```

Comment: I am not really sure where these dictionaries come from, I only operate with dataframes. So using .values won't work.

Answer (score 0):

An approach may be using [`pandas.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html), which demands:

1. The *same* column names and the *same* shape on both dataframes.
2. The orders of the rows being *consistent* between dataframes -- this can be achieved by preprocessing the dataframes (e.g., using sorting).

The code:

```
df1.iloc[:,0:5].compare(df2.iloc[:,0:5])
```

Output:

```
  attribute_1       attribute_2        attribute_3         
         self other        self  other        self    other
0         NaN   NaN       378.8  478.8      Accept  Decline
2         NaN   NaN         NaN    NaN     Decline   Accept
3          B-    C-         NaN    NaN         NaN      NaN
```